# How to replace all non-alphabetic characters with UTF-8 support in PHP

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace

I want to remove all non-alphabetic character from a string. The problem is that I don't know the letter range because it is UTF8 string.

It can be ENGLISH, ՀԱՅԵՐԵՆ, ქართული, УКРАЇНСЬКИЙ, РУССКИЙ

I usually do something like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $str);
```

or

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w]/u', '', $str);
```

but they both clear foreign characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As for Unicode, RegExp will look like this **`[^\p{L}\s]+`** (without replacing spaces)

It will replace all non-alpha characters with UTF8 support.

- `\P{L}+` - matches any non-letter symbols
- `\p{P}+` - removes punctuation only

Here are some reference docs that can be helpful:

- [Tutorial on RegExp UTF8](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)
- [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: "Alphabetic" doesn't mean only characters used in English.

Comment: @cleong, Sorry, my fault, missed that point. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I think both answers are super, but I think this got more info

Answer (score 10):

Use the [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/u', '', $str);
```

Comment: As a side note, it's worth mentioning the syntax for specifying a Unicode character class when the u flag is used. Curly brackets are needed around the code points. For example, `[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]` matches any characters in the regular Cyrillic range.

Comment: How do you have to change the Regex to also keep numbers (next to the alphabetic ones) and not remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Unicode property for letter is `\pL`, for non letter is `\PL`

```
$str = preg_replace('/\PL+/u', '', $str);
```