# Regular expression matching Unicode and Number string

Tags: java, android, regex

#### Problem Description

I have string **"Վիկտոր1 Ափոյան2"** using regular expression I want to get first letters of both strings. So as a result I will have **"ՎԱ"**  As string is unicode I'm musing following regex:

```
"(\\p{L})\\p{L}*\\s(\\p{L})\\p{L}*
```

Which works fine if string does not contains numbers **"1"**, **"2"**, to get result I also tried with following regex:

```
"(\\p{L}\\p{N})\\p{L}\\p{N}*\\s(\\p{L}\\p{N})\\p{L}\\p{N}*
```

but this does not work correct.

Is there a something like **"\\p{LN}"** which will check for Unicode letters and numbers at the same time, or anyone knows how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a something like "\p{LN}" which will check for Unicode letters and numbers at the same time

Use a character class `[\p{L}\p{N}]` that will match either a Unicode letter or a digit.

Alternatively use `\p{Alnum}` with a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag (or prepend the pattern with `(?U)`).

Comment: What would be the regex to replace every character that is *not* unicode or numeric?

Comment: @Avatar Every char is Unicode. To match any non-digit, use `\P{N}` or `\D`.

Comment: Oh, I meant how to allow only alphabetic characters with UTF-8 and numbers. Actually coming from https://stackoverflow.com/q/11989482/1066234 and found your answer here. `preg_replace` removes them, so we need a regex that catches all others.

Comment: @Avatar `[\p{L}\p{N}]` is a positive character class, it matches any chars that are defined inside it: letters and digits. To match anything but those chars, make the character class a negated character class, `[^\p{L}\p{N}]`.